# Rephrasing 'dividing the tasks?'

Tags: word-choice

What is the proper way to rephrase **dividing the tasks**? Does **splitting the tasks** more appropriate?
The complete sentence is,

> Dividing the tasks would greatly help.

Comment: They both sound okay to me.

Comment: I think you would be understood either way, but I think that *"splitting **up** the tasks"* sounds a bit more idiomatic to me.

Comment: [tranching](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tranche) ;)

Comment: Do you mean "sharing the tasks between a number of people" or "dividing each task into several subtasks?"

Answer (score 1):

I feel divide is used when you divide a noun that is countable, or in a formal tone. We say split a bill, but not divide a bill, because it sounds casual.
But in Pledge of Allegiance, we say the country is indivisible.